# What's a good way to sharpen a carpenter's pencil, without buying a special sharpener?

Tags: planning, sharpening

I have a carpenter's pencil that's getting pretty blunt and I've realised I don't know how to sharpen it.

How can I sharpen it without buying a special dedicated tool for it?

Comment: Sure you use the sharpener most carpenters have - a utility knife

Comment: Home depot sells a pack of pencils and a sharpener for maybe 2 dollars? Why waste your time?

Comment: @gunner a utility knife? There's no fun in that! For proper pencil sharpening, you want yourself a nice professional power grinder!

Comment: I usually use what I have at hand, be it a chisel, brick, sidewalk. I too have tried a beaver, but they eat the rest of the pencils. :-)

Comment: How is this a real question? How do you sharpen a pencil, seriously?

Comment: @iambriansreed, carpenter's pencils aren't round so they don't fit in your standard pencil sharpener... I would never have thought of using a plane, so I'm glad I asked!

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=%22how+to+sharpen+a+carpenter%27s+pencil%22

Comment: For what it's worth, some finish carpenters and woodworkers have started using mechanical pencils. Of course the serious woodworker who wants absolute precision uses a marking knife.

Answer (score 15):

Whatever you have handy. There are many tools that would work, besides a pencil sharpener dedicated to this.

- A pocket or utility knife - cut away from you of course.
- A sliding, compound miter saw (overkill, but it will work well enough.)
- A belt sander
- A band saw
- A drum sander in your drill press (or an oscillating drum sander if you have one in the shop.)

The point is, a carpenter's pencil is mainly wood, and can be shaped by any tools you have in reach that can also shape wood.

Comment: +1 for having an excuse to buy a sliding, compound miter saw

Comment: Tim the tool man would've said ... "He who dies with the most toys wins."

Comment: A pencil is pretty small, I'd definitely upgrade the miter saw to include the laser guides.

Comment: These are all good answers. I chose to take a different approach, however, and have managed to train a beaver to do all my pencil sharpening for me. Alas, I found out beavers like to chew things and now have to order pencils by the case on an almost daily basis to keep him busy.

Comment: I took that advice, and went out and bought a beaver. Sadly, the beaver soon got bored with pencils. Then he started "sharpening" the legs on our chairs, all the trees around our house, the posts for our deck, even a neighbors wooden leg. Does anyone know where I can find a mountain lion so I can get rid of the beaver?

Comment: I have a 24 pound cat with an attitude if you can't find a lion.  She (Rosie) rents out at reasonable rates.

Answer (score 4):

The perfect tool is sitting right there on your tool shelf - your hand plane. Hold it upside down in your nondominant hand and slide the pencil across the blade with your dominant hand. Be careful!

Answer (score 2):

Use a knife. One of these should always be in your belt:

[image: knife]

Comment: For carpenters, it would likely be a utility knife, but close enough. Just cut from the wood away from you to the lead point.

Comment: plus vote for a simple utility knife. A simple plastic carpenter's pencil sharpener is only a few bucks, but I lose them! So back to the knife.

Answer (score 1):

Keson makes a carpenters pencil sharpener that puts a chisel point on the lead.  The only way to sharpen a carpenters pencil is to a chisel point.  Available at Northern Tool.

Answer (score 1):

I sharpen mine with a pocket knife. I leave about 1/4" of lead showing, then I bevel the tip of the lead to a chisel point, that way I can get a clean crisp line. You can use sandpaper to get a chisel point, but I just use my knife most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

My Dads a finish carpenter,he's 95 and still has at least two pencils with him at any time. Remember as a kid watching him sharpen his pencil with his pocket knife. Always took his time, had 12 facets on the point all perfect. Always said don't get in hurry and do it right...